# Unit Testing and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

Where can I find either literature or video demonstration of unit testing applications using VB.NET? As a novice/hobbyist programmer I would like to build a solid foundation in developing applications using the unit testing methodology.

Comment: Are you using the express versions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it helps any, you may want to learn C# if you plan on staying in the .NET world and ever plan to use .NET professionally.  I've answered why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260325/which-net-programming-language-should-i-learn-as-a-web-developer#260389).  Now, on to your question: O'Reilly and Associates had an [article on this very subject](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/07/18/unittesting_2005.html) recently (if by 2005 you mean recent, but for our purposes, we can call it recent).  You may also want to learn [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php), which is a unit testing framework for .NET.

As far as Books:

- [Open Source .NET Development](http://safari.oreilly.com/0321228103) - Covers Nunit.
- [eXtreme .NET: Introducing eXtreme Programming Techniques to .NET Developers](http://safari.oreilly.com/0321303636)
- [Test Driven Development in Microsoft.NET](http://safari.oreilly.com/0735619484)

That should get you started.  I don't know whether the code examples are in VB or C#, but if you have a [Safari online](http://safari.oreilly.com/) subscription (which I highly recommend), you'll be able to browse these books without dropping money on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some info on [unit testing vb](http://www.typemock.com/vbpage.php) on Typemock’s site